# Solution such that an inequality is true in the whole domain

Tags: inequalities

How to find out when an inequality is always true in a given domain? I give an example below.

I would want to find $b(a)$ such that the following is always true:

$\quad~x + a > bx$, where $0 < x < 1$, $a > 0$, $b > 0$

The answer is obviously $b \le a + 1$ but I could not find it with `SolveAlways` which is seemingly limited to equalities.

`Reduce[x + a > b*x && a > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < x < 1, {b}]` gives the following:

```
                              a + x
a > 0 && 0 < x < 1 && 0 < b < -----
                                x
```

`Reduce[x + a > b*x && a > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < x < 1, {x}]`:

```
                                                                   a
a > 0 && ((0 < b <= 1 + a && 0 < x < 1) || (b > 1 + a && 0 < x < ------))
                                                                 -1 + b
```

in this particular case happens to gives the solution but only as an embedded fragment.

The following `Simplify[Reduce[x + a >  b*x], Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < x < 1]` yields $a + x > b x$.

I also tried `SolveAlways[{x + a > b*x, a > 0, b > 0, 0 < x < 1}, x]`, `SolveAlways[x + a > b*x && a > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < x < 1}, x]`, `Eliminate`, various applications of `Assuming`. I never obtained $b(a)$, however.

Comment: Why do you think "The answer is obviously  `b≤a+1`"? `Reduce[ForAll[{x, a}, 0 < x && x < 1 && a > 0 && b > 0, 
  x + a > b*x ], b, Reals]` produces `b<1`.

Comment: I think, since the OP wants to find b as a function of a, b(a), means b and a are regarded variable, he wants it to be valid for all x. Then `Reduce[ForAll[x, 0 < x && x < 1, x + a > b*x] && a > 0 && 
  b > 0, b, Reals]` yields the result `b <= 1 + a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way than proposed in the comments is as follows.

```
Reduce[Minimize[{x + a - b*x, x > 0 && x < 1 && a > 0 && b > 0}, 
 x][[1]] >= 0 && a > 0 && b > 0]
```

> `a > 0 && 0 < b <= 1 + a`