# Find a function for which an inequality is always true: performance problems

Tags: performance-tuning, inequalities

I have this inequality which compares paths of two motions against time $t$:

[image]

Machine-generated code:

```
Piecewise[{{Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[aRx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vR0]]], And[GreaterEqual[t, 0], LessEqual[t, rho]]}, {Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[-1, aRx, Power[rho, 2]], Times[-1, bRx, Power[rho, 2]], Times[2, aRx, rho, t], Times[2, bRx, rho, t], Times[-1, bRx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vR0]]], And[GreaterEqual[t, rho], LessEqual[t, Times[Power[bRx, -1], Plus[Times[aRx, rho], Times[bRx, rho], vR0]]]]}}] <= Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[2, d], Times[-1, bFx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vF0]]]
```

I am interested in relations between the constants $\rho > 0, v^F_0 > 0, v^R_0 > 0,$ $b^F_x > 0, a^R_x > 0, b^R_x > 0, d > 0$ (i.e. all variables in the equation except for the time $t$). Specifically, I want to find $D(\rho, v^F_0, v^R_0, b^F_x, a^R_x, b^R_x)$ such that $d \ge D$ is true iff the inequality above is always true in the time period

[image]

Code:

```
0 < t && t < Times[Power[bRx, -1], Plus[Times[aRx, rho], Times[bRx, rho], vR0]]
```

Using Wolfram Engine, I tried both solutions from [Solution such that an inequality is true in the whole domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270132/83186), i.e. `Reduce[ForAll[]]`:

[image]

```
Reduce[ForAll[t, 0 < t && t < Times[Power[bRx, -1], Plus[Times[aRx, rho], Times[bRx, rho], vR0]], Piecewise[{{Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[aRx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vR0]]], And[GreaterEqual[t, 0], LessEqual[t, rho]]}, {Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[-1, aRx, Power[rho, 2]], Times[-1, bRx, Power[rho, 2]], Times[2, aRx, rho, t], Times[2, bRx, rho, t], Times[-1, bRx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vR0]]], And[GreaterEqual[t, rho], LessEqual[t, Times[Power[bRx, -1], Plus[Times[aRx, rho], Times[bRx, rho], vR0]]]]}}] <= Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[2, d], Times[-1, bFx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vF0]]]] && vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRx > 0, d, Reals]
```

and `Reduce[Minimize[]]`:

[image]

```
Reduce[Minimize[{(Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[2, d], Times[-1, bFx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vF0]]]) - (Piecewise[{{Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[aRx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vR0]]], And[GreaterEqual[t, 0], LessEqual[t, rho]]}, {Times[Divide[1, 2], Plus[Times[-1, aRx, Power[rho, 2]], Times[-1, bRx, Power[rho, 2]], Times[2, aRx, rho, t], Times[2, bRx, rho, t], Times[-1, bRx, Power[t, 2]], Times[2, t, vR0]]], And[GreaterEqual[t, rho], LessEqual[t, Times[Power[bRx, -1], Plus[Times[aRx, rho], Times[bRx, rho], vR0]]]]}}]), 0 < t && t < Times[Power[bRx, -1], Plus[Times[aRx, rho], Times[bRx, rho], vR0]] && vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRx > 0}, t][[1]] >= 0 && vF0 > 0 && vR0 > 0 && bFx > 0 && rho > 0 && aRx > 0 && bRx > 0]
```

However, due to long computation times, I interrupted both calculations after about half an hour.

I wonder if there is a method of formalising the problem (for at least the case of piecewise quadratic functions as above) which does not cause such performance problems.

**EDIT:** I forgot to add one more constraint: $b^F_x > b^R_x$.

Comment: Your piece-wise expression depending on 6 parameters is too complex for both approaches.  If you put `aRx = 2; vR0 = 1; bRx = 4; Fx = 1; rho = 3; bFx = 3;`, then `Reduce[ForAll...]` produces `d >= 1359/32` as well as `REduce[Minimize...]`.

Comment: The `Reduce[Minimize...]` approach works for `R0 = 1; bRx = 4; Fx = 1; rho = 3;`. The result is too long to be presented here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit, Answer with $b_x^F>b_x^R$

Simplest solution. Redefine your inequality so it's $f(t)\leq d$

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[{{(aRx*t^2 + 2*t*vR0)/2 + (bFx*t^2)/2 - t*vF0, 
     t >= 0 && t <= rho},
    {(-(aRx*rho^2) - bRx*rho^2 + 2*aRx*rho*t + 2*bRx*rho*t - 
         bRx*t^2 + 2*t*vR0)/2 + (bFx*t^2)/2 - t*vF0, 
     t >= rho && t <= (aRx*rho + bRx*rho + vR0)/bRx}}, 0];
```

Set up the constraints

```
tmax = (aRx*rho + bRx*rho + vR0)/bRx;
cons = And @@ Flatten[{Thread[vars > 0], bFx > bRx}];
const = 0 < t && t <= tmax;
```

Note that $f$ is strictly concave up under these constraints

```
Simplify[(D[f[t], {t, 2}] >= 0), cons && const] (*True*)
```

This means the maximum value of $f(t)$ is at one of the ends of your time interval, i.e. $t=0$ or $t=t_{\max}$, and you're done.

```
dbound = Max[Simplify[f[0], cons], Simplify[f[tmax], cons]]
```

Which matches the other solutions below and gives a tight bound on $d$.

### First Edit

The key is to simplify as much as possible before trying to call `Reduce`.

Begin with your setup

```
Clear[f, g, tmax]
f = Piecewise[{{(aRx*t^2 + 2*t*vR0)/2, t >= 0 && t <= rho}, {(-(aRx*rho^2) - bRx*rho^2 + 2*aRx*rho*t + 2*bRx*rho*t - bRx*t^2 + 2*t*vR0)/2, 
   t >= rho && t <= (aRx*rho + bRx*rho + vR0)/bRx}}, 0];
g = (2*d - bFx*t^2 + 2*t*vF0)/2;

ineq = f <= g;

tmax = (aRx*rho + bRx*rho + vR0)/bRx;
vars = {rho, aRx, vR0, bRx, bFx, vF0, d};
```

and your constraints

```
const = 0 < t && t <= tmax;
cons = And @@ Flatten[{Thread[vars > 0], bFx > bRx}];
```

"Solve" your inequality for $d$ given the constraints

```
dsol = Refine[Reduce[ineq, d], cons && const] (*0.2s on my machine*)
```

`Resolve` this solution for all times in the interval

```
resolve = Simplify[Resolve@ForAll[t, const, ineqd], cons] (*0.2s*)
```

`Reduce` again to get back to inequalities for $d$

```
reduce = Refine[Reduce[red, d], cons] (*6.5s*)
```

This gives 2 possibilities

[image]

Fortunately, we can show the 2nd possibility is never valid under our constraints. Let's split up the possibilities and check for solutions. Here's a hack way to do it

```
sols = reduce /. Or -> List /. GreaterEqual[d, x__] -> Equal[d, x]
```

Then we have

```
Reduce[Last[sols] && cons]==False
```

Note that this is not `False` if we remove the $d\geq 0$ constraint, so we can simply discard the final solution as long as we enforce $d\geq 0$ manually at the end, e.g. with `Max`. This then immediately gives the answer:

```
dbound = Max[0,Last@Last@First@sols];
```

Which is the same as in the original answer when $b_x^F>b_x^R$.

This is a lower bound, $D=$`dbound`, on $d$ which is tight. That is, $d\geq D$ iff your inequality holds true and furthermore, setting $d=D$ guarantees that the two sides of your inequality will be equal for some $t$ between $0$ and $t_{\text{max}}$ - actually *at* $t=0\to D=0$ or $t=t_{\max}$ since $b_x^F>b_x^R$ enforces a certain concavity as explained in the original answer below.

## Original answer

### TL;DR - use

```
d1[aRx_, vR0_, rho_, bRx_, bFx_, vF0_] = 1/2 (-aRx rho (rho - 2 t) - bRx (rho - t)^2 + t (bFx t - 2 vF0 + 2 vR0));
dbound[aRx_, vR0_, rho_, bRx_, bFx_, vF0_] := Block[{d1a, tmax, tm, t},
  tmax = (aRx rho + bRx rho + vR0)/bRx;
  d1a = d1[aRx, vR0, rho, bRx, bFx, vF0];
  Max[0, If[bFx >= bRx, d1a /. t -> tmax, 
    tm = t /. First@Solve[D[d1a, t] == 0, t]; 
    If[tm > tmax, d1a /. t -> tmax, d1a /. t -> tm]]]
  ]
```

### Actual Answer

How tight do you need this bound?

Consider your setup

```
f=Piecewise[{{Times[Divide[1,2],Plus[Times[aRx,Power[t,2]],Times[2,t,vR0]]],And[GreaterEqual[t,0],LessEqual[t,rho]]},{Times[Divide[1,2],Plus[Times[-1,aRx,Power[rho,2]],Times[-1,bRx,Power[rho,2]],Times[2,aRx,rho,t],Times[2,bRx,rho,t],Times[-1,bRx,Power[t,2]],Times[2,t,vR0]]],And[GreaterEqual[t,rho],LessEqual[t,Times[Power[bRx,-1],Plus[Times[aRx,rho],Times[bRx,rho],vR0]]]]}}];
g=Times[Divide[1,2],Plus[Times[2,d],Times[-1,bFx,Power[t,2]],Times[2,t,vF0]]];
tmax=Times[Power[bRx,-1],Plus[Times[aRx,rho],Times[bRx,rho],vR0]];
```

and constraints (const is in that form because Mathematica reduces smarter that way, don't ask me why).

```
const = 0 < t && Refine[Reduce[t <= tmax, VR0], cons && t > 0];
cons = And @@ Thread[{rho, aRx, vR0, bRx, bFx, vF0, d} > 0];
ineq = f <= g;
```

We can immediately "solve" this for $d$

```
ineqd = Refine[Reduce[ineq, d], cons && const]
```

giving 2 possibilities for $D$ depending on if $t<\rho$ or $t>\rho$.

If $t>\rho$ we have
$$
d\geq\frac{1}{2} \left(t^2 b_x^F-\rho  (\rho -2 t) a_x^R-(\rho -t)^2 b_x^R\right)=d_1(t)
$$

If $t<\rho$ we have
$$ 
d\geq\frac{1}{2} t (t (a_x^R+b_x^F)-2 v_0^F+2 v_0^R)=d_2(t)
$$

which we store as `ds = Last[Last[#]] & /@ List @@ (ineqd)`

If you don't need a tight bound, note that

`FullSimplify[Reduce[First@ds <= Last@ds], cons && const]` is `True` so $d_2(t)\geq d_1(t)$ for all $t$. Thus for a loose bound, we can simply ignore $d_1(t)$. Further note that `FullSimplify[D[Last@ds, {t, 2}] > 0, cons]` is `True` so $d_2(t)$ is concave up in $t$ meaning its maximum is either $d_2(0)=0$ or $d_2(t_{\text{max}})$ meaning we have

$$
d\geq \max{0,\frac{\left(\rho  \left(a_x^R+b_x^R\right)+v_0^R\right) \left(a_x^R \left(\rho  \left(b_x^F+b_x^R\right)+v_0^R\right)+\rho  \left(a_x^R\right)^2+b_x^F \left(\rho  b_x^R+v_0^R\right)+2 \left(v_0^R-v_0^R\right) b_x^R\right)}{2 \left(b_x^R\right)^2}}.
$$

However, this is less tight of a bound than is possible given your initial inequalities. It gets a bit ugly if you want to tighten it up.

Since $d_1(t)\leq d_2(t)$ and $d_2(t)$ stops being valid when $t>\rho$, you know the maximum of $d_1(t)$ in $\rho<t<t_{\text{max}}$ is the "true" lower bound on $d$.

If $d_1(t)$ is concave up or linear, i.e. `D[First@ds, {t, 2}] >= 0` or $b_x^F\geq b_x^R$, then the maximum of $d_1(t)$ in $\rho<t<t_{\text{max}}$ is $d_1(t_{\text{max}})$ or $d_1(t)$ is strictly negative in this interval and we take $d=0$. This can be verified by the fact that `Reduce[And[Flatten[{(First@ds /. t -> rho) > (First@ds /. t -> tmax), (First@ds /. t -> rho) >= 0, bFx > bRx, cons}]]]` is `False`

If $d_1(t)$ is concave down, i.e. $b_x^F<b_x^R$, $d_1(t)$ has a maximum, call it $t_m$. Either $t_m<\rho$, $t_m>t_{\text{max}}$ or $t_m$ is somewhere between. If $\rho\leq t_m \leq t_{\text{max}}$ then $d\geq\max{0,d_1(t_m)}$ is your solution. If $t_m<\rho$, $d>0$ is your solution because

```
tm = t /. First@Solve[D[First@ds, t] == 0, t];
Reduce[And[Flatten[{(First@ds /. t -> rho) > (First@ds /. t -> tmax), (First@ds /. t -> rho) >= 0, bFx < bRx, cons, rho > tm > tmax}]]]
```

gives `False` tells you that $d_1(t)$ is strictly negative in this interval.

And finally if $t_m > t_{\text{max}}$ then $d\geq\max{0,d_1(t_{\text{max}})}$ is your solution.

So putting it all together

```
d1[aRx_, vR0_, rho_, bRx_, bFx_, vF0_] = First@ds;
dbound[aRx_, vR0_, rho_, bRx_, bFx_, vF0_] := Block[{d1a, tmax, tm, t},
  tmax = (aRx rho + bRx rho + vR0)/bRx;
  d1a = d1[aRx, vR0, rho, bRx, bFx, vF0];
  Max[0, If[bFx >= bRx, d1a /. t -> tmax, 
    tm = t /. First@Solve[D[d1a, t] == 0, t]; 
    If[tm > tmax, d1a /. t -> tmax, d1a /. t -> tm]]]
  ]
```

gives you a lower bound, $D=$`dbound`, on $d$ which is tight. That is, $d\geq D$ iff your inequality holds true and furthermore, setting $d=D$ guarantees that the two sides of your inequality will be equal for some $t$ between $0$ and $t_{\text{max}}$.

Comment: When I typed `ineqd` into WE, I got a piecewise $d_1(t)$ depending on $v^R_0 < -(a^R_x \rho) - b^R_x \rho + b^R_x t$. How did you obtain such an equation of $d_1(t)$? Also, I forgot to add a constraint $b^F_x > b^R_x$.

Comment: `Reduce` should never return `Piecewise`. It should give you an expression with And and Or. Is that not what you get?

Comment: Yes you are right. How can $d_1(t)$ be obtained from it?

Comment: It's given in the answer. `ds = Last[Last[#]] & /@ List @@ (ineqd)`. Then $d_1=$`First@ds`. I'm working on an update to the answer. With the constraint $b_x^F>b_x^R$ everything becomes simple.

Comment: @scriptfoo, realized with the new constraint the problem is even simpler than I thought. Final edit made, very simple answer :)

Comment: This is only one of many cases, the other may not have that constraint, so the original answer still contains useful information.